# How to prevent assignment of wrong type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I'm new to TypeScript and want to get rid of wrong types sneaking into my data structures. I thought TypeScript would forbid the following assignment of `this.myString = myArgument` since the type of `myArgument` is unknown.

```
class MyClass {
    private myString : string;

    constructor(myArgument) {
        this.myString = myArgument;
    }
}

let myInstance = new MyClass(3);
console.log("my instance", myInstance);
```

At runtime `myInstance.myString` will be a number which is highly undesirable :( I know I probably could add `myArgument : string` as parameter argument type declaration but I thought one of the strengths of TypeScript is type inference which should be easy here?

How can I prevent wrong types ending up in my data structures?

Comment: well.. it can't infer what type myArgument will be.. it could be anything. The way to go is to specify a type for it.

Comment: But I'm calling `new MyClass` with 3, which should flag this invocation as incorrect. Or is this indeterminable because i could do anything in the constructor (halting problem). At least an untyped variable should never be allowed to be assigend to a typed one, just the other way around, shouldn't it?

Comment: in your case, the type of myArgument is **any** thus the invocation is correct. if you want you can just disable any completely with a compiler option in tsconfig.json "noImplicitAny": true,

Comment: also, Typescript doesn't do any runtime checks, only compile time and static analysis. At runtime all type information is lost and all that's left is plain js. :)

Comment: Thanks `noImplicitAny` was what I was looking for! Might you provide that as an answer to be accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure that all values must have specified types you can set `noImplicitAny` to true in `tsconfig.json`.