# Custom type string with validation "EmailAddress"

Tags: javascript, validation, typescript

Below I have a bit of typescript code. My intention here is to create a new custom type for an email address, a `string` with specific validation. I'd like a way of ensuring the string argument is already validated as a specific type. The code below does not throw any validation errors as I'd expect.

```
class EmailAddress {
    constructor (emailAddress) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        if (!re.test(emailAddress)) throw new Error('invalid email address')
    }
}

function exampleTakesEmail (email: EmailAddress) {
    return {
        email
    }
}

let email = new EmailAddress('example@gmail.com')
let notEmail = ''

console.log(exampleTakesEmail(email))
console.log(exampleTakesEmail(notEmail))
```

Of course if I run this:

```
let email = new EmailAddress('')
```

Then I do get an error.

Comment: You mean this does not throw any error or warning? `console.log(exampleTakesEmail(notEmail))`. I write js but not typescript, but I expect that passing a string where your function expects an `EmailAddress` object should throw some kind of error or warning

Comment: I'm compiling and running and getting this. `{ email: EmailAddress {} }\n{ email: '' }`

Comment: Not sure if I'm running correctly. I'm running `tsc example.ts` and then running `node example.js`.

Comment: I think your second email address should be `new EmailAddress('')`, and not just an empty string

Comment: Also just ran it with `ts-node` and it ran without errors.

Comment: @kennasoft that will surely throw. The functionality I want is on the function level, I want to ensure the function is receiving what it accepts.

Comment: Oh, ok. Maybe there is a compile time error that you are not seeing. I don't use ts, so I can't render much help in the compiler errors

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, you want some sort of error to be thrown from `exampleTakesEmail` when the argument is not of type email address and not from `EmailAddress` ctor.

I think after compiling the TypeScript to JavaScript, the type information is not retained like you expect it to be. Thus, if you wan the type checking you may think of using `instanceof` operator, which looks something like this:

```
class EmailAddress {
    constructor (emailAddress) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        if (!re.test(emailAddress)) throw new Error('invalid email address');

    }
}

function exampleTakesEmail (email: EmailAddress) {
    if(!(email instanceof EmailAddress)) throw new Error("Not email")
    return {
        email
    }    
}

let email = new EmailAddress('example@gmail.com')
let notEmail = ''//new EmailAddress('abc')

console.log(exampleTakesEmail(email))
console.log(exampleTakesEmail(notEmail))
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/rpbt0xjo/

---

**Additional resource:**
From [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-check-at-runtime-if-an-object-implements-some-interface):

> TypeScript types are erased (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) during compilation. This means there is no built-in mechanism for performing runtime type checks. It's up to you to decide how you want to distinguish objects.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this! This is super similar to the solution @Val gave. A way of validating the argument from within the function. But I really anticipated typescript to handle this kind of validation for me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

Let's try this:

```
class EmailAddress {
    constructor (emailAddress) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        if (!re.test(emailAddress)) throw new Error('invalid email address')
    }
}

function exampleTakesEmail (email: EmailAddress) {
    return {
        email
    }
}

let email = new EmailAddress('example@gmail.com')
let notEmail = new EmailAddress('') //construct an empty string EmailAddress first

console.log(exampleTakesEmail(email))
console.log(exampleTakesEmail(notEmail))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, time, and energy! But this is not what I'm looking for. I'm specifically looking for functionality so that the last line throws an error.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't somewhere to turn on error reporting?

Comment: I saw this: Maybe it will cause compilation to fail? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38805753/299708

Comment: @kennasoft - that should ensure that no arguments passed into functions are without type I think.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function exampleTakesEmail (email: EmailAddress | string) {
    return typeof email==="string" ? 
            new EmailAddress(email) : email;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution here! I feel that this totally defeats the purpose of having type scripting. I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to check the type of argument within the function.

Comment: But you actually provide a string not an instance of EmailAddress. From my understanding no strongly-typed language would accept that. So what we did here is to detect it, and convert to real EmailAddress instance.

Comment: I think that's the point he's precisely trying to prove with typescript. Does it deliver on its promise of strict typing?

Comment: @Val check my answer apparently flow types does this, so there's one that accepts it.

Answer (score -1):

**This works as expected with [flow types](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAUQFtsBLGAQQBNqAnAU3zAG9UwOwM4A7XAFzoBXDPzh0wACgakKNek1wBKVu07qAbtgmMwAXjDAAepMkBtIwB4AfJKUAdM-YC69+wDoANAG4AXPdwIACJnAGpJDwsbO0cXNy8-AOCwpRAlAB9JIPdQoKUlCFNHMwAGAFoATmcWAEZPAGYAX0jyqtqG5vdSyuq6ppae9qbnDNMzbDKAL0oygC17MtawjyVQ8amZ2eqAJk9G-IASNHV1MigpAEJGd34mfmlZKlpGfHywfgALOkQwHgYkQh0b50SQAcjIPC0MDI1DAMnIMDA2GeilBSjUHEaqCxqCgQh4ojIvDhAA9sMQAA4wBgAFWwAGsmCQEVJ4RRfERHvIXspVOpGPwhHQeHyThw2TAMWAsTjqfw4Y99L9-pyEdzFGCGGTKdSIABzR7ubjENGoOW-OD8ZkUJWg0Hobh8ODU9zwPXSbVU2kMpmPSQ8S3WmD5VBAA) an alternative to typescript!**

The following in flow does not throw:

```
/* @flow */

class EmailAddress {
    constructor (emailAddress) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        if (!re.test(emailAddress)) throw new Error('invalid email address')
    }
}

function exampleTakesEmail (email: EmailAddress) {
    return {
        email
    }
}

let email = new EmailAddress('example@gmail.com')
let notEmail = ''

console.log(exampleTakesEmail(email))
```

Where this does throw, as I'd expect:

```
/* @flow */

class EmailAddress {
    constructor (emailAddress) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        if (!re.test(emailAddress)) throw new Error('invalid email address')
    }
}

function exampleTakesEmail (email: EmailAddress) {
    return {
        email
    }
}

let email = new EmailAddress('example@gmail.com')
let notEmail = ''

console.log(exampleTakesEmail(notEmail))
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question. @thomasreggi need "throw email validation error of empty string" but you give answer to "compile time error" which is out of topic.

Comment: @ThomasReggi It seems that your objective "I've been trying to find the main difference between flow types and typescript.." is different than the posted question. Don't you think that need another question that clearly state that?

Comment: @Val this answer demonstrates how flow catches the error when the function runs and receives an argument that is not valid, that's exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @SayanPal My objective was to get the code above in the question to work as expected, I'd love to do that with `typescript` and I found a that `flow` works as expected with the same code, I thought that was relevant to my question, and I think it's relevant to note the difference between the two here.

Comment: Your original question didn't show that at all. IMHO downvote others answer which may just try to be helpful, and self-answered with which may seems somewhat out topic, won't make things any better.

Comment: @Val The real answer here is how to do it in typescript the way that flow types does it, if it's possible. I posted this mainly to show you that this was possible.